# How can I access TextMate grammars for *already loaded languages* in VSCode?

Tags: typescript, parsing, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to create a Visual Studio Code extension that enables and disables font ligatures depending on syntactic context. In particular, in most cases, I only want ligatures applied to operators, not to strings or comments or variable names or anything else.

Extensions have access to all of your open documents. Unless I'm missing something, however, as far as I can tell VScode doesn't give you, as an extension developer, any direct insight into how any of those documents are being parsed. Even though automatic parsing is clearly happening already (as can be seen by built-in syntax coloring) all I've got access to that I can see is the text of my document, broken down into lines, and I can find matching editor object, but no hints about the parsing of the text that's already being done behind the scenes.

It seems absurd that I'd have to parse the text all over again inside my extension, but apparently that's what I have to do.

Further, I can't even see a straight-forward way to tell TextMate how to parse a document without either providing my own copy of a TextMate grammar for every language I want to be able to handle, or by somehow rummaging through VSCode's extensions and tracking down all of the grammars buried inside there myself.

I tried to use an existing extension as a model for my extension (Scope Info: https://github.com/siegebell/scope-info), but that hasn't been updated in three years, and doesn't appear to work with current versions of VSCode anymore. It looks like that extension had a trick for using built-in grammars, but that trick doesn't work anymore.

Does anyone know an easier way to do this?

Comment: I know nothing about it, but you can try asking on vscode extensions Slack: https://vscode-dev-community.slack.com/

Comment: @Mosh Feu, thanks for the tip! It's been crickets there so far (the "vscode-extension-dev" channel doesn't look like a very active Slack channel), but hopefully I'll get some help eventually.

Comment: I saw your message. Maybe it's a hard one :) I don't know that answer either.